# What is considered standard when dealing with database errors in a REST application?

Tags: node.js, database, rest, error-handling, sequelize.js

I'm currently writing a public REST service in Node.js that interfaces with a Postgres-database (using Sequelize) and a Redis cache instance.
I'm now looking into error handling and how to send informative and verbose error messages if something would happen with a request.

It struck me that I'm not quite sure how to handle internal server errors. What would be the appropriate way of dealing with this? Consider the following scenario:

I'm sending a post-request to an endpoint which in turn inserts the content to the database. However, something went wrong during this process (validation, connection issue, whatever). An error is thrown by the Sequelize-driver and I catch it.

I would argue that it is quite sensitive information (even if I remove the stack trace) and I'm not comfortable with exposing references of internal concepts (table-names, functions, etc.) to the client. I'd like to have a custom error for these scenarios that briefly describes the problem without giving away too detailed information.

Is the only way to approach this by mapping every "possible" error in the Sequelize-driver to a generic one and send that back to the client? Or how would you approach this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add your code here

Comment: I'm not sure how a code-example would help in this conceptual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors are always caused by something. You should identify and intercept these causes before doing your database operation. Only cases that you think you've prepared for should reach the database operation.

If an unexpected error occurs, you should not send an informative error message for security reasons. Just send a generic error for unexpected cases.

Your code will look somewhat like this:

```
async databaseInsert(req, res) {
  try {
    if (typeof req.body.name !== 'string') {
      res.status(400).send('Required field "name" was missing or malformed.')
      return
    }
    if (problemCase2) {
      res.status(400).send('Error message 2')
      return
    }
    ...
    result = await ... // database operation
    res.status(200).send(result)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(debugging ? e : 'Unexpected error')
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This makes a lot of sense.